# Add to favorites in JavaScript for IE6+, FF and Safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8, favorites

I tried some "add to favorties" JavaScript scripts.. With IE8, I get an "access denied" (is that even possible to add a bookmark via JS with IE8?) and it just doesn't work with IE6...
Anybody has a good script that works on most browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: I will never understand why web sites feel the need to have 'add to bookmarks' buttons. Web browsers make it very easy to bookmark pages without having to find a link in the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both IE6 and IE8 will need the users to press CTRL+D to add the website to the favourites.

Edit: Sorry, I run into a brain malfunction and mixed some words out.

Actually, IE8 allows javascript to manage the favourites.

To be more precise, and if you use jquery on your website, here's an example :

```
    $("a.bookmark").click(function(e) {
            if ($.browser.opera == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = this.href;  
                var title = this.title;

                if ($.browser.mozilla == true) {
                    window.sidebar.addPanel(title, url, '');
                    return false;
                } else if($.browser.msie == true) {  
                    window.external.AddFavorite( url, title);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    alert('Please use CTRL + D to bookmark this website.');
                }


    }
});
```

Note: the "a.bookmark" is required to work with opera, since it recognizes .bookmark class in anchor tags and executes the bookmark funcion on click.

It supports IE7 & 8, Firefox 2 & 3, and Opera 9 (at least) .. Safari isn't supported, and IE6 I couldn't test it here, sorry.

Comment: window.sidebar.addPanel makes the bookmark open in the sidebar, not in a new tab, which is not what most people want. I think the Ctrl+D message is the only way to get the correct result in FF.

Answer (score 1):

I have a client who wants this. So far as tested this is a totally 100% cross platform solution. Not only does it give the standard bookmarking functionality, but it educates your user at the same time :) :) :)

I've tested it as working on Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Code is below:

```
<a class="button" onClick="alert('Hold down Ctrl and D at the same time to add this to your favourites')">Bookmark</a>
```

.. now the real question is whether to use confirm or alert. Confirm may give the users a reassuring but false sense of control about whether they added the bookmark or not?

Comment: Tried it on Chrome, FF, and Safari on MacOS.  Didn't work. :-)  Also, can't find control key on my app phone.

Comment: smart arse :P :-) If I try hard I might be able to work an app phone version and possibly a mac version. Multi-lingual too (repeat message in several languages). It's a very versatile technique :) Point taken though.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html) looks solid. But I'd recommend that you test it across whatever browsers you plan to support.